# What is the best system to use in Android to push data update notifications to clients only while app is running and in foreground

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, publish-subscribe

I am considering using GCM but I do not want the device to get notifications when the app isn't being displayed. The updates are only useful when the user is in the app.

I have looked at various services that provide pub sub / push services and most of them seem to target just web browsers. I would like to use GCM if possible, and last resort I will just have to poll the web service every few minutes while the app is running.

The service will be sending out data update notifications approximately every 4-6 minutes 24/7/365 to those devices that are subscribed to the particular channel. The user wants the updates as quick as possible, but not while the app is closed. I feel that if I just throw away these notifications when the user is not in the app, it will be unnecessarily wasting battery and data.

My current strategy, unless I use a push strategy, is to start polling every 1 minute when I expect there to be an update (5 minutes after the last update). and then repeat. Once the app is closed, the polling will stop.

Comment: Have you looked at [Parse.com](https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#options-data/Android)? They allow you to send a message without an "alert" string, which means it will not appear in the Notification Centre, but [your application can handle the message as it sees fit](https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#receiving-responding/Android). Note that they use GCM under the hood.

Comment: Some users will only be in the app for 10 minutes per week. I do not want to send notifications every 4-6 minutes 24 hours a day to these devices. I only want updates while the app is in the foregroud. Parse is just another system to deliver the same message, I was also looking at Amazon SNS

Comment: One way is [using advanced targetting](https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending-queries/REST) and setting a "wantMessages" flag to "true" when your app is in the foreground.

Comment: First off, your question is off-topic; recommendations for services are verboten here, as it attracts spam and opinions. That said, ignore the Parse spam, GCM will do what you need **and is free**. When your app launches, have it ask the server for updates; have it repeat that request every 60 minutes. Once the server receives a request, have it send updates through GCM with collapsible key for 65 minutes. You can tweak the times... but you'll get timely updates while the app is active, and no updates when it isn't, with just a moderate amount of waste.

Comment: @323go Thanks. I understand the client side part of this method. Can you explain the server side portion a bit more. Does the server side need to store some device/user identifier with this strategy, or is there some magic I am missing?

Comment: The device would register with the server, and the server would hold a device ID... that's basic GCM patterns. When the client checks in, the server would update the check-in time-stamp, and then push notifications only if this tms is within the last hour. However, you're throwing away the major benefits of push notifications here, as they're really designed to reach an app even when it's not active. If you really only need updates every five minutes, polling might be the way to go.

Comment: @323go If you make this an answer I can accept it. This helped

Comment: I added an answer, making it a bit more general. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll take this question as asking for a pattern, rather than a recommendation for a tool.

There are various ways of dealing with server-to-client notifications in general, not just in Android.

When utilizing push-notifications, on Android, GCM would be preferred. In order to only receive notifications when the app is active, the app could check in with the server, and basically subscribe to notifications for a limited time. The server would hold the device-Id for each registered device, and keep a time-stamp of the most-recent check-in. If a new event occurs, the server would then push notifications to all clients which have been active within a certain time period. (For example, if the client checks in every 30 minutes, the server would deliver messages for 35 minutes).

The advantage here is that the push notifications could carry a payload, and so the data arrives automatically in the app. Waste would be limited, as no messages would be delivered after the app has become idle or was exited.

Of course, one of the major points of push notifications is the ability to reach an app which isn't active, and that wouldn't apply here.

However, if the payload is relatively small and the update frequency is low, then polling may be preferable. You'll know almost immediately if there are communication issues, and you could poll immediately when the network becomes available. With an update interval of five minutes, battery drain would be negligible.

Answer (score -1):

[Parse.com](https://www.parse.com/) offer the tools to do what you want, and the basic offering is free. (Disclosure: I don't work there - I've just used their product on an internal demo app).

In your main Activity, for instance, you could add:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    ParseUser user = /* however you want to log in, etc */;

    user.put("wantMessages", "no");
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ParseUser user = /* however you want to log in, etc */;

    user.put("wantMessages", "yes");
}
```

Now you can [send messages from your server](https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/REST) like so:

```
curl -X PUT \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: XWMoibK5LL86NsU2GIy02ozXx2YiggG4kJL9q4Eg" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: yIIdNdZRSuZxeKpa7a1CyjxrAORMJ5mtcC4BQdE1" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
        "where": {
          "wantMessages": "yes"
        },
        "data": {
          "new-data-url": "https://download.from.here/data.txt"
        }
      }' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/push
```

Thus, only the users with the app in the foreground will get the message.

Comment: Is wantMessages server side or client side flag? Do the messages get sent and ignored?

Comment: The flag is saved server-side in the Parse databases, and messages will not get sent.